# Selenium doesn't navigate text with shortcuts like CMD+UP or ALT+UP

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

On any text form, I can use CMD+UP to navigate at the very top or OPTION+UP to navigate to the start of the paragraph. That works in any browser on macOS.

Why it does not work from Selenium?

I tried this in Java and an equivalent in Typescript -

```
new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.ALT).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP).keyUp(Keys.ALT).perform();
```

Surprisingly, I can jump words using ALT+ARROW_LEFT.

Is there any workaround to jump to the beginning of the paragraph?